# Descriptive Statistics table for several variables and by group

Tags: r, statistics, tidyverse, stargazer

I'm trying to create descriptive statistics in a "publishable" html format.

Let's take the mtcars data and assume I want to create a table that gives me the usual descriptive statistics for Miles/(US) gallon, Gross horsepower, Weight (1000 lbs), and 1/4 mile time for both automatic and manual cars.

I can get a rough version of what I am looking for by using psych::describeBy

```
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)

#Descriptive statistics
data("mtcars")

df <- mtcars|>
  select(1,4,6,7,9)

describeBy(df, group = mtcars$am, fast=TRUE)
```

However, I am trying to create this in a format that is close to what you would find in journal articles and also can be exported as html. Anyone got any suggestions? I tried to use stargazer but struggled to get results for both groups in one table.
Thanks!

Comment: df <- mtcars 

You didnt set the df variable.

Comment: Did you try `gtsummary`

Comment: Or `modelsummary`? It has a very helpful `datasummary` function and various derivatives ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is minimal raw data for `mtcars` grouped by `am` with `gtsummary`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
as_tibble(mtcars)

library(gtsummary)
mtcars %>% tbl_summary(by = am)
```

[image]

You can have various modifications (labels etc.) in `gtsummary`.